# Disable .toggleClass after an element has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a tictactoe game. Player 1 selects his marker, x or o, then the tictactoe board appears. Player 1's marker, let's say x, will appear at 0.5 opacity whenever he hovers over an empty cell. On click, the cell receives a .addClass("clicked"), which inserts the marker into the cell at 1 opacity. I have a .toggleClass function to switch between player markers. I would like player 1's x to remain on the board, while player 2's hovers show an o on any empty cell. The issue I am having is that after I click on a cell to add my x in, the entire board toggles class. I want every cell that does not have the class "clicked" to toggle. How can I do this?

Here is the code if player 1 chooses x

```
case "x":
    $(function(){
        $(".board").addClass("o");
        $("td").click(function(){
            $(this).children("p").addClass("clicked x");
            $(".board").toggleClass("x o");
        });
    });
    break;
```

CSS

```
.x td:hover p {
    content:url("images/X.png");
    opacity:0.5;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.o td:hover p {
    content:url("images/O.png");
    opacity:0.5;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.x .clicked {
    content:url("images/X.png");
    opacity:1;
}

.o .clicked {
    content:url("images/O.png");
    opacity:1;
}
```

HTML

```
        <table class="hidden board" cellspacing="0">
            <p class="bigTitle hidden" id="turn">Player Turn</p>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="a1"><p></p></td>
                <td id="a2"><p></p></td>
                <td id="a3"><p></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="b1"><p></p></td>
                <td id="b2"><p></p></td>
                <td id="b3"><p></p></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="c1"><p></p></td>
                <td id="c2"><p></p></td>
                <td id="c3"><p></p></td>    
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the function to each individual cell instead of the board, and check within the function if the cell has the `clicked` class.

```
$(function(){
    $(".board td").addClass("o");
    $("td").click(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ) {
            $(this).children("p").addClass("clicked x");
            $(this).toggleClass("x o");
        }
    });
});
```

Modify the CSS selectors accordingly, for example

```
td.o:hover p { ...
.x.clicked { ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a "!" in front of the if condition. The only problem I am having is toggling which class to add. However, that is a separate question. Thank you for helping me!